# sqlite_fetch_object() is undefined

Tags: php, sqlite, object, fetch

I am trying to implement a sqlite data layer for an assignment for a class. in the mysqli layer, I used mysqli_fetch_object with no issues. I am trying to do the same thing with sqlite, but it comes with an error saying it is an undefined method. This is the method that is using fetch_object:

```
public function selectActor($actorId)
{
    $this->stmt = @$this->dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM actor WHERE actor_id = :actorid");
    $this->stmt->bindParam(':actorid', $actorId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $this->stmt->execute();

if (!$this->stmt) {
    die('Could not retrieve records from the Sakila Database: ' .
        $this->dbConnection->error);
}
$return = sqlite_fetch_object($this->stmt);

return $return;//returns object
}
```

Is this the correct method to use? Does it require another parameter or something?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using. Looks like this function only exists < 5.4. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-fetch-object.php

Comment: @chris85 I thought that might have been the reason, but intellisense usually has a note that the method is deprecated and it didn't seem to be coming up.

Comment: Actually you are using PDO already, cancel previous message. Use PDO fetch, http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php.

Comment: That worked, thanks! for future reference, the last line was:         $return = $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);